# PHP Bcrypt move to Python3

Tags: python-3.x, bcrypt, blowfish

I need to move original php auth verification to python3. I have code like this:

```
// hash from db
$hash = "$2y$14$00sMXcXPyTthEv9m5dszwuT8VUU6KK1HtCunemfutphrbCHZoIz0e";

// the hash is used as salt
$result = crypt($password, $hash);

//result should match the hash if pasword is correct 
$result = "$2y$14$00sMXcXPyTthEv9m5dszwuT8VUU6KK1HtCunemfutphrbCHZoIz0e";
```

It is done with parameter cost = 14

What is the best lib to implement it in python3?

EDITED:
I used lib [py-bcrypt](https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/).

```
>>> import bcrypt  
>>> password = "ahoj"
>>> db_hash = "$2y$14$00sMXcXPyTthEv9m5dszwuT8VUU6KK1HtCunemfutphrbCHZoIz0e"
>>> computed_hash = bcrypt.hashpw(password, db_hash)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid salt
```

Why is salt invalid?

In PHP it works:

```
password=ahoj
hash=$2y$14$00sMXcXPyTthEv9m5dszwuT8VUU6KK1HtCunemfutphrbCHZoIz0e
result=$2y$14$00sMXcXPyTthEv9m5dszwuT8VUU6KK1HtCunemfutphrbCHZoIz0e
```

What is different in python?

Comment: It's a standard bcrypt hash, any library will handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare passwords, use the `checkpw` function instead of `hashpw`:

```
if bcrypt.checkpw(passsword, db_hash):
    print "It matches"
else:
    print "It does not match"
```

Salt is needed only when you generate a new hash:

```
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

You can find more details in the [README](https://code.google.com/p/py-bcrypt/source/browse/README) file.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Its still not working. Im getting **ValueError: Invalid hashed_password salt**

Comment: @JoeBobson: replace "$2y" with "$2a" - `py-bcrypt` only understands the latter at the moment. for most passwords this should make no difference.